# Change image on mouseover for a button on another div

Tags: javascript, css

On the "home" page I want to have a logotype and a menu on a `#banner div` (which will then be there throughout the whole site) and on a `#content" div` to have an image. All these `div`s are inside a `#container" div`. The menu has 3 buttons.

I would like that on `mouseover` event each button displayed image on the `#content div` changes accordingly. So basically, when hover `button1`, the image on `#content` will change from `background.jpg` to `background1.jpg`. The event of `mouseover` on `button2` will change it to `background2.jpg` etc. When buttons are not hovered over, the image should revert to the original `background.jpg`.

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>E.S.T.</title>
  <link href="_css/layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="SpryAssets/SpryMenuBarHorizontal.css" 
        rel="stylesheet" 
        type="text/css">
  <script src="SpryAssets/SpryMenuBar.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="banner">
      <div id="logo">E.S.T.</div>
       <div id="menu">
         <ul id="MenuBar1" class="MenuBarHorizontal">
           <li id="button1"><a href="bio.html">Biography</a></li>
           <li id="button2"><a href="#">Albums</a></li>
           <li id="button3"><a href="#">Links</a></li>       
         </ul>
       </div>
     </div>
   <div id="content">
     <img id="back0" src="_img/background.jpg">
     <img id="back1" src="_img/back_bio.jpg">
   </div>
 </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var MenuBar1 = new Spry.Widget.MenuBar("MenuBar1,
  {
    imgDown:"SpryAssets/SpryMenuBarDownHover.gif",
    imgRight:"SpryAssets/SpryMenuBarRightHover.gif"
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
@charset "UTF-8";
@import url("../_fonts/Days/fontstylesheet.css");

body {
  background-color:#CCC;
  font-family:Days;
  font-size:100%;
}

#container {
  width:850px;
  max-height: 650px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: Days;
}

#logo {
  position:relative;
  font-size: 4em;
  color:white;
  float:left;
}

#menu {
  float:right;
  margin-top:40px;
}
```

I have tried several different things but I manage only to change the background image from the buttons themselves. From searching around the web i think this should be done with JS, but i have no idea how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved entirely with CSS, but first let me give you a tip:
Combine `background.jpg` and `background1.jpg` into one image, and rather change the background position. This way, there won't be any delay from when the user hovers over the menu element to when the picture is displayed, and you'll have fewer files to keep track of.

Say we let `#button1` be 100px tall. We make an image 200px tall containing the normal state image on top, and the hover image on the bottom. This is called a [sprite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprite_%28computer_graphics%29).

```
#button1 {
    height: 100px;
    background-image: url("background.jpg");
}

#button1:hover {
    background-position: 0 -100px;
}
```

This moves the background image, showing the hover version.

Comment: This sounds a simple idea, if the background.jpg would be the backgound of the button. the background image is not the background of the button (it's the background "of the site")
The image and the button are inside different divs.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I totally misread your question (as did @AlessandroMinoccheri I believe). I'll just submit a new answer in a few minutes, ok?

Answer (score 0):

Give an id on your image like: id=idimage
You can use jQuery like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#MenuBar1 li").mouseover(function(){
        var id=$(this).attr('id');
        var number = id[id.length-1];
        $("#id_image").attr("src","_img/background"+number+".jpg");
    });  
});  
</script>
```

Comment: where in the code should i put this?
I tried it out, it looks like a smart solution, but it tells me that there is a syntax error in the last line, where there is "</script>"  (?!?) and then the images don't change.
Do we need to somehow load the images beforehand?
I have some other scripts inside the html code. Can there be any kind of conflict?

Comment: no more syntax errors!  But the images are still not changing!

Comment: You image has the div id="id_image"?

Comment: The image is inside a div with id="content" and i have added id="id_image" to the code:

<div id="content"> <img src="_img/background.jpg" alt="e.s.t." name="idimage" width="850" height="539" id="id_image">

Comment: I have modified again and works into my server.You have to put before the name of the image (into the script) the path of your img in this case: _img try!

Comment: maybe it didn't work here because of the same reason the idea from Jurgemaister also doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

For convenience, I'll answer this question using the [`jQuery`](http://jquery.com) javascript library.

If I understand you right, you would like `#content` to contain an image that changes when you hover over the menu items, and the image should reflect the item currently hovered.

In stead of including every image in the body, I'll try an approach using the `data` attributes.

**HTML** ***The relevant parts***

```
<ul id="MenuBar1" class="MenuBarHorizontal">
    <li id="button1" data-img="background.jpg"><a href="bio.html">Biography</a></li>
    <li id="button2" data-img="back_album.jpg"><a href="#">Albums</a></li>
    <li id="button3"><a href="#">Links</a></li>       
</ul>

<div id="content">
    <img id="back"
         src="_img/background.jpg"
         data-original="_img/background.jpg" 
         alt="e.s.t" />
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#MenuBar1 li").mouseover(function() {
        $("#back").attr("src", $(this).data("img"));
    }).mouseout(function() {
        $("#back").attr("src", $("#back").data("original"));
    });
});​
```

So now we store the original image path with the image tag in its `data-original` attribute, and the path to the `:hover` image is stored with the menu element.

See this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LNrfL/) for a demo!

Comment: that seems to be what i have been looking for. let me try it out...   (where should i put the JavaScript? Same code? Attached file?)

Comment: Put it between `<script>` tags in your `<head>`. Oh! And you need to include jQuery. Either just link to it the same way you do with the other JavaScripts with [this](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.1.min.js) URL or download it and link to it locally.

Comment: it doesn't give any error, it shows the "normal" image, but nothing changes when i hover the buttons.
In the script, when you write "#back" what is it refering to?

Comment: Look at my code. There's an image with the id `back`. You can call it whatever you like, of course. Did you remember to include jQuery in your page?

Comment: i have updated the code up in my original question to show you how it looks now.

Comment: Please don't change the question. Rather post a link to a paste, like with [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or similar. And take time to read the answers to understand them. Understanding is key if you want to learn something from this, not just have working code.

Comment: sorry. i am trying to understand it. I have tryied it in JSFidle: http://jsfiddle.net/jPhC2/

Comment: It may seem that your "Spry" library causes trouble. Impossible to say as it isn't actually loaded in the fiddele. Removing the references to Spry (and the doubled up js in the header) it works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/jPhC2/2/

Comment: on dreamweaver, the code hints don't show me any "data-img". when i type "data-" i get a list of hints but img is not on there.

Comment: `img` is just something I added. You can name your data variables whatever you like.